# spectrum of $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

When $A=\bigoplus B(\Bbb C^n)$ ($c_0$ direct sum),how to compute the spectrum of $A$ ?What about the conclusion If we replace the $\ell ^\infty $ direct sum with $c_0$ direct sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be a character of $A$. The composition $\tau\circ\pi_n$ where $\pi_n$ is the projection onto the $n^{\rm th}$ coordinate, is a character of $M_n(\mathbb C)$; which has none unless $n=1$.

So the only character of $A$ is $a\longmapsto a_1$, assuming that the first coordinate is one-dimensional.

Comment: Pro Argerami,why the character of $M_n(\Bbb C)$ has none?

Comment: Because the kernel is an ideal in $M_n(\mathbb C)$.